# Public alpha/beta testing on google play - as benign as it sounds?

Tags: android, google-play

You provide your app - to which you probably devoted a lot of time/energy/money - to be tested by strangers. If they find it impressive, what will prevent them from cloning your app and releasing it before you get yours out of the beta?

Comment: nothing, that what is called a free market

Comment: @Taier wow, Sad

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts:

- how do I protect my *idea* during beta testing?
- how do I protect my *code* during beta testing?

The first question isn't really a programming question, it is more a business question. How do you stop someone seeing your idea and writing a clone themself. There are basically two answers. The first is legal: use whatever legal means are available in your jurisdiction (Trademark, copyright, patent) and enforce it legally. The second is strategic: have a strategy that makes your idea difficult to copy. One way is solve a problem so difficult that no-one can do it as well as you (like Google with websearch). Another is to take advantage of network effects - like Facebook a social media platform is only valuable if users are there.

The second question is more applicable to StackOverflow. It has a few answers:

- Google Play scans for pure copycat apps. If someone just extracts your app and re-signs it it will get detected and the developer copying it get banned
- Google offer a "[License Verification Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview)" (LVL) to detect if your app has been installed from somewhere other than Google Play
- Google offers the [SafetyNet attestation API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) to let you check if your app has been signed by a different key

Comment: Thank you for the answer, may I know what implications does LVL have. How does knowing whether an app was installed from somewhere else help someone? Also if your app is only available in playstore then it can't be installed from anywhere else right?

Comment: LV was introduced as an anti-piracy measure. Even if your app is only distributed via the Play store, people can (and do) pull the APKs off their devices and then distribute them via other methods, and possibly even upload them to other App stores. LVL protects against this.